# Smtp on plesk panel : cannot send email

Tags: email, smtp, plesk

I'm working with parallels plesk panel (here 11.5 on centOS 6.4) since 2 years and i got a problem yesterday:
My server refuse connection from my mail client.

Client (outlook) & DNS : https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCxxs.jpg

And smtp plesk configuration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnvPo.jpg

They are using same authentification method, no ssl, default port... I don't understand

-
I turned off the firewall while I have problems.

I tried to switch postfix/qmail it doesn't work. I don't understand why it accept mail from the webmail located on the server but not on clients.

Some help will be welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a DNS issue..

Depending on your hosting provider, you original settings may have been changed on their end. ICANN may also be changing their DNS policies as well.

Adding this to your DNS records...

webmail.yourdomain.com. 600 A yourIP